# Django Model with composite primary key isn't updated

Tags: python, django

I have a model with composite primary key

> ```
> class ChatUserModel(CModelMixin):
>     user = models.ForeignKey(Users, models.DO_NOTHING, primary_key=True)
>     chat = models.ForeignKey(ChatModel, models.DO_NOTHING)
>     chat_permissions = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
>
>     class Meta:
>         managed = True
>         db_table = 'tbl_chat_users'
>         unique_together = (('user', 'chat'),)
> ```

And service, which use this model

> ```
> def connect_to_chat(self, serializer: ChatInfoSerializer) -> ChatUserModel:
>
>     chat_id = serializer.validated_data.get('chat')
>
>     if ChatUserModel.objects.filter(user_id=self.user.id, chat_id=chat_id).exists():
>         raise exceptions.ValidationError('User is already member of this chat')
>
>     bundle = ChatUserModel.objects.create(user=self.user, chat_id=chat_id)
>
>
>     if self.user.status == enum_status_of_user.confirmed_email:
>         bundle.chat_permissions = ChatPermissions.canWrite.value
>         bundle.save()
>
>     return bundle
> ```

when running, I get an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) psycopg2.errors.UniqueViolation: duplicate key value violates unique
> constraint "pk_tbl_chat_user_user_id" DETAIL:  Key (user_id,
> chat_id)=(26b01213-b9c3-4abc-b1d2-f7213781a2c6,
> ef4f0c4f-8edf-42b5-b01f-880856d55cd4) already exists.
>
> The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py",
> line 47, in inner
> response = get_response(request)   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py",
> line 181, in _get_response
> response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py",
> line 54, in wrapped_view
> return view_func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py",
> line 70, in view
> return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
> line 509, in dispatch
> response = self.handle_exception(exc)   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
> line 469, in handle_exception
> self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
> line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
> raise exc   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py",
> line 506, in dispatch
> response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/projects/webcam_test_dev/webcam-backend/webcam69/chat/views/ConnectChatView.py",
> line 18, in post
> chat.connect_to_chat(serializer)   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/projects/webcam_test_dev/webcam-backend/webcam69/chat/services/ChatService.py",
> line 54, in connect_to_chat
> bundle.save()   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> line 753, in save
> self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert,   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> line 790, in save_base
> updated = self._save_table(   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> line 872, in _save_table
> updated = self._do_update(base_qs, using, pk_val, values, update_fields,   File
> "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py",
> line 926, in _do_update
> return filtered._update(values) > 0   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py",
> line 803, in _update
> return query.get_compiler(self.db).execute_sql(CURSOR)   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
> line 1522, in execute_sql
> cursor = super().execute_sql(result_type)   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py",
> line 1156, in execute_sql
> cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 98, in execute
> return super().execute(sql, params)   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 66, in execute
> return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)   File
> "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 75, in _execute_with_wrappers
> return executor(sql, params, many, context)   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/utils.py",
> line 90, in **exit**
> raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value   File "/Users/tatyanakorneeva/.local/share/virtualenvs/webcam-backend-GgKKOkUN/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py",
> line 84, in _execute
> return self.cursor.execute(sql, params) django.db.utils.IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique
> constraint "pk_tbl_chat_user_user_id" DETAIL:  Key (user_id,
> chat_id)=(26b01213-b9c3-4abc-b1d2-f7213781a2c6,
> ef4f0c4f-8edf-42b5-b01f-880856d55cd4) already exists.

Object being created, then we go into the loop with 'if' (condition is true) - the object cannot be updated.
I think Django instead update instance try create, but i don't know why.
Parameter force_update=True didn't help me.

Comment: You set `primary_key=True` on user making it the primary key for the table, hence receiving the error. Just use unique together and let Django create it's own primary key column

Comment: You don't understand - object being created, it's ok. In the loop he cannot be updated. If i delete the code:     if self.user.status == enum_status_of_user.confirmed_email:
        bundle.chat_permissions = ChatPermissions.canWrite.value
        bundle.save() - everything will be allright

Comment: You have a OneToOne field with user this means one user can only have one entry in this table, then what is the meaning of adding a unique together with user and chat? user already has a unique constraint then you say user and chat are unique together isn't that already satisfied by user being unique?

Comment: I update model - replace OneToOne with ForeignKey, but still i have same error

Comment: user being the primary key still means user is unique... Also add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: I added full traceback. And i tried remove primary key from the field "user", but: 1) Django created new field 'id' with primary key - i don't need extra field, this is not the best solution. In another projects (not django) have composite keys without extra-field 'id' 2) I received error: django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "tbl_chat_users"

Comment: You could check my project. I make a virtual primary key field to trick Django, and allow to use tables with composite keys without schema altering - https://viewflow.medium.com/the-django-compositeforeignkey-field-get-access-to-a-legacy-database-without-altering-db-tables-74abc9868026